Export `stdout` and `stderr` of a single-line bash command to text file while using python module followed by `-m` syntax
I would like to export the stdout and stderr of a bash command to the same text file.
The bash command is a single-line command that calls python3 followed by the name of the module and function, followed by three arguments (each using --).
The bash command is running on an HPC as part of a slurm job.
python3 -m module.function --Arg1 Val1 --Arg2 Val2 --Arg3 Val3 

I tried the following but it failed. It assumes that 2> or > are extra information to the last argument.
python3 -m module.function --Arg1 Val1 --Arg2 Val2 --Arg3 Val3 2> Output.txt
python3 -m module.function --Arg1 Val1 --Arg2 Val2 --Arg3 Val3 > Output.txt

How to be able to export the output to a file without making large changes to the syntax (I need to keep using a single line command for calling the function from the module).
Thanks

How exactly are these commands being run? If they're run directly in bash, they will redirect stdout / stderr as expected. Are they being stored in a variable and then run from that, or something similar?

I created a list of these python commands using R and saved to a text file. Then, I use the following bash command to run each line of these commands as separate job in parallel: $(head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID $File | tail -n 1) [submitted as a SLURM array job]

Sounds like slurm isn't running the command through the shell, so everything is treated literally.

You can try the command bash -c 'python ... >Output.txt 2>&1'. Hopefully slurm will respect the quotes.

This is a slurm problem, not a bash problem or a Python problem. If your command were being parsed by bash it would work as-intended.

The problem does not lie in the Bash syntax but in the way you run the command:

Then, I use the following bash command to run each line of these
commands as separate job in parallel: $(head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID
$File | tail -n 1) [submitted as a SLURM array job]

this indeed execs the command which is interpreted as is without any involvement of Bash.
Try this instead:
head -n $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID $File | tail -n 1 | bash

Now beware that with > Output.txt for every lin in $File, each job will overwrite the Output.txt file, leaving you only with the output of the last job in the array. Using >> Output.txt will not overwrite, but the result on parallel jobs is not guaranteed. Best is to
And if you want both stderr and stdout to be merged you need >& Output.txt.
But if that is the only line in the submission script, you might prefer simply using the Slurm --output="slurm-%A_%a.out parameter. If you need everything in a single file afterwards, use the cat command.

This works as expected. Thanks a lot for your help.

Given you have Python, you could wrap your process in subprocess to control the output
Shared stdout stream
python3 -c 'import subprocess;subprocess.check_output("python3 -m module.function --Arg1 Val1 --Arg2 Val2 --Arg3 Val3".split(),stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,text=True)'

direct the output to a file named "path"
python3 -c 'import subprocess;f=open("path","w");subprocess.check_output("python3 -m module.function --Arg1 Val1 --Arg2 Val2 --Arg3 Val3".split(),stdout=f,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,text=True)'

Notes about subprocessing

.split() is a hack to pass a simple string which will be separated by spaces into a list, while subprocess.check_output() is expecting a collection of values, which may include spaces
text=True automatically .decode()s the output, assuming the encoding .. if you'd like to set it yourself, drop the argument and decode the result yourself .. additionally, older Python versions without text=True (introduced in 3.7) may set universal_newlines=True instead

